# How to ensure that initializer_list is not zero

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a constructor that accepts a initializer_list as argument:

```
A::A(std::initializer_list<uint32_t> arg)
    : vec(arg)
{
}
```

The issue is that it allows initializer_list zero or empty values for arg:

```
A {}
```

How can I force a non-zero initializer_list ?

Comment: You can't validate the `initializer_list` at compile-time (so `static_assert()` is out), but you can throw an exception at run-time if it is empty: `A::A(std::initializer_list<uint32_t> arg) : vec(arg) { if (arg.size() == 0) throw std::invalid_argument("arg list can't be empty"); }`.

Comment: Maybe you could change to non-zero length variadic template instead of initializer_list

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the initializer is `{}`, a default constructor takes precedence over a `std::initializer_list` constructor, but the latter will be used when the former is not present. Therefore, in order to force a compile error, you need to explicitly delete the default constructor, so that the default constructor is still selected but cannot be used:

```
struct A {
    A() = delete;
    A(std::initializer_list<uint32_t>) { /* ... */ }
};
```

However, at compile time, you can't stop the user from manually constructing an empty `std::initializer_list` object and passing it in. You would need to throw an exception to signal construction failure in that case.

Comment: Please explain - "However, at compile time, you can't the user from manually constructing an empty std::initializer_list object and passing it in. You would need to throw an exception to signal construction failure in that case." - is it that user can still pass empty std::initializer_list ?

Comment: He's talking about cases like `A var{std::initializer_list<uint32_t>{}};`, or even `A var2{{}};`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - should I just add a check that if the size is 0 create at least 1 element with value 0 as I do not wish to halt the code by throwing an exception - maybe the caller should ensure its values - is my approach correct?

Comment: Another option is to make a variadic template constructor and assert that the size of the pack is greater than 0.

Comment: @Programmer Don't you want to halt the code and let the caller know he's an idiot?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this *with initializer lists* -- you'd have to do run-time (not compile-time) validation.

But, just for fun: if you are willing to forego initializer lists, and accept an array as an input into your constructor, you can get what you want.

```
class A {
 private:
  std::vector<int> v_;
 public:
  template<typename T, std::size_t N>
  A(const T(&v)[N]) : v_(std::begin(v), std::end(v)) {
    static_assert(N > 0, "Requires nonempty array.");
  }
};

int main() {
  int empty_arr[] = {};
  int arr[] = {1};
  // The following no longer works as there is no constructor that takes in as
  // input an initializer list.
  // A a{1};
  // A b{};
  A c({2});
  // So does this:
  A d(arr);
  // And this would be a compilation error, even if there was no static_assert.
  // C++ standard says you can't have an array of size zero. The static_assert in 
  // the class is just to make it easier for others to see what your intention is.
  // A e(empty_arr);
}
```

Comment: `int empty_arr[] = {};` is an error, there must be at least 1 initializer clause for an array of unknown bound

Comment: You're right, it's `gcc` being forgiving that lets me do that. But it still causes a compile-time error in the template, which is the point I was trying to make.